# Celery worker is running, but suddenly the node is not replying any more

Tags: redis, celery

I have a celery worker with redis backending running for more than half a year and I did not have any problems so far.

Suddenly, I do not get any reply from the nodes.

I can successfully start celery, there is no error message when executing the command:

```
celery multi start myqueue -A myapp.celery -Ofair
celery multi v4.3.0 (rhubarb)
> Starting nodes...
> myqueue@myhost: OK
```

However, when I check the status of the celery worker

```
celery -A myapp.celery status
```

I get the message:

```
Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.
```

If I look up the processes, the celery worker appears to be running:

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m celery worker -Ofair -A myapp.celery --concurrency=4
\_ /usr/bin/python3 -m celery worker -Ofair -A myapp.celery --concurrency=4
\_ /usr/bin/python3 -m celery worker -Ofair -A myapp.celery --concurrency=4
\_ /usr/bin/python3 -m celery worker -Ofair -A myapp.celery --concurrency=4
\_ /usr/bin/python3 -m celery worker -Ofair -A myapp.celery --concurrency=4
```

When I do a

```
celery -A myapp.celery control shutdown
```

the above processes are removed as expected.

Starting in the foreground does not give any hint either:

```
$ celery -A myapp.celery myworker -l debug
Please specify a different user using the --uid option.

User information: uid=1000120000 euid=1000120000 gid=0 egid=0


uid=uid, euid=euid, gid=gid, egid=egid,
[2019-08-23 11:36:36,790: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Preparing bootsteps.
[2019-08-23 11:36:36,792: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Building graph...
[2019-08-23 11:36:36,793: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: New boot order: {StateDB, Beat, Timer, Hub, Pool, Autoscaler, Consumer}
[2019-08-23 11:36:36,808: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Preparing bootsteps.
[2019-08-23 11:36:36,808: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Building graph...
[2019-08-23 11:36:36,862: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: New boot order: {Connection, Events, Mingle, Tasks, Control, Heart, Gossip, Agent, event loop}

 -------------- celery@myapp-163-m4hs9 v4.3.0 (rhubarb)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial 2019-08-23 11:36:36
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         myapp:0x7f2094fcd978
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://:**@${redis-host}:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://:**@${redis-host}:6379/0
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> myqueue      exchange=myqueue(direct) key=myqueue


[tasks]
  . sometask1
  . sometask2
[2019-08-23 11:36:36,874: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Hub
[2019-08-23 11:36:36,874: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2019-08-23 11:36:36,874: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
[2019-08-23 11:36:37,278: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2019-08-23 11:36:37,279: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
[2019-08-23 11:36:37,280: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
[2019-08-23 11:36:37,299: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://:**@${redis-host}:6379/0
[2019-08-23 11:36:37,299: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2019-08-23 11:36:37,299: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Events
[2019-08-23 11:36:37,311: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2019-08-23 11:36:37,312: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Mingle
[2019-08-23 11:36:37,312: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,343: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,343: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,343: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Tasks
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,350: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,350: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Control
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,359: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,359: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Heart
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,363: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,363: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Gossip
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,371: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,371: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting event loop
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,372: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Hub.register Pool...
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,373: INFO/MainProcess] celery@myapp-163-m4hs9 ready.
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,373: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->16
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,838: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
[2019-08-23 11:36:38,839: INFO/MainProcess] Events of group {task} enabled by remote.
[2019-08-23 11:36:43,838: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method enable_events() [reply_to:None ticket:None]
```

Redis is up an running:

```
redis-cli -h ${redis-host}
redis:6379> ping
PONG
```

The log file does not contain any hint.

As already mentioned, when I check the status of the celery worker

```
celery -A myapp.celery status
```

I get the message:

```
Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.
```

Instead, celery should respond with

```
> myqueue@myhost: OK
```

or at least give some error message.

Interim solution and further investigation:

For now, the immediate measure was to switch the message queue to RabbitMQ and the worker is online and responding again. So this issue seems to be specific to using Redis as message queue.
Updating Celery/Redis-client to the most recent versions (Celery 4.3.0, redis 3.3.8) did not help.
Python version is 3.5 (on OpenShift).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in the latest version (4.6.4) of the Kombu library (a Celery dependency) which causes this issue with Redis as documented in [this Github issue](https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/1087).

The bug was [recently fixed in a pull request](https://github.com/celery/kombu/pull/1089) in the Kombu repository but hasn't made it to a release yet.

Downgrading Kombu to version 4.6.3 will fix the issue.